# How should I allow only registered users to post in the site?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am creating a website where the user is posting his information in the site, the problem am facing is that even when I have logged out still I can post. I want only registered and logged in users to be able to post in the site

This is for python 3.7.3, Django 2.2.3, MySQL 5.7.26, I want to post only when am logged in, unfortunately, I can post in both ways, when being logged in and logged out, which means anybody can post even if he/she, not a registered user

views.py

```
def PostNew(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
        return redirect('loststuffapp:IndexView')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'loststuffapp/form.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class Documents(models.Model):
    docs_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item_type = models.CharField(default="", max_length=100, help_text='*Enter the item name you found e.g. Marksheet,key,wallet')
    police_station = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='*Enter the police station you sending the docs')
    phone_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='*Enter full description about item')
    pay_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(default="add Item image", upload_to="DocsImage",blank=False)

    """docstring for Documents"""
    def __str__(self):
        return self.docs_name
```

home.html

```
{% extends "loststuffapp/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="/PostNew">Add documents</a>

 {% for Doc in documents %}
 <div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">

    <p>{{Doc.docs_name}}</p>
    <p>{{Doc.item_type}}</p>
    <p>{{Doc.police_station}}</p>
    <p>{{Doc.phone_no}}</p>
    <p>{{Doc.Description}}</p>
    <p><img src = "/media/{{Doc.image.url}}" width = "240"/></p>
    <p>{{Doc.date}}</p>

 </div>
</div>
</div>
 {% endfor %} 

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have you heard about _session variables_ ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I think I have to through it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@login_required` decorator before your view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def PostNew(request):
   # code
```

**Now before posting anything user must need to be logged in.**

Comment: @Kelvin, You can select the answer if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: I have another question, i need your help. The answer you gave me yesterday  worked perfect, now what I want is that once the user fail to access the site I want him/her to see the message "Register new account to post documents" instead of Page is not found. Please help!!

Comment: @login_required will take them to login page. Now they will try to login. So in login controller you check if the username doesn't exist redirect to register and give message to create new account or if username exists and still can't log in either password is wrong or user is inactive. Given the message accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have understood the flow